# RandomForestClassifier give transposed output for multi-label classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

For some reason, whenever I run a `ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()` and use the `.predict_proba()` method, it returns a 2d-array in the shape of `[n_classes, n_samples]` instead of the `[n_samples, n_classes]` shape that it's supposed to [per the docs.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

Here is my sample code:

```
# generate some sample data

X = np.array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
              [0, 5, 6, 2, 3], 
              [1, 2, 6, 5, 8], 
              [6, 1, 1, 1, 3], 
              [2, 5, 3, 2, 0]])
»» X.shape
   (5, 5)

y = [['blue', 'red'], 
     ['red'], 
     ['red', 'green'], 
     ['blue', 'green'], 
     ['orange']]

X_test = np.array([[4, 6, 1, 2, 8], 
                   [0, 0, 1, 5, 1]])
»» X_test.shape
   (2, 5)

# binarize text labels

mlb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
lb_y = mlb.fit_transform(y)

»» lb_y 
   [[1 0 0 1]
    [0 0 0 1]
    [0 1 0 1]
    [1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 0]]

»» lb_y.shape
   (5, 4)
```

Everything works fine up until this point. But when I do this:

```
rfc = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
rfc.fit(X, lb_y)
yhat_p = rfc.predict_proba(X_test)

»» yhat_p
[array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0.7,  0.3]]), 
 array([[ 0.4,  0.6],
        [ 0.5,  0.5]]), 
 array([[ 0.7,  0.3],
        [ 0.7,  0.3]]), 
 array([[ 0.7,  0.3],
        [ 0.6,  0.4]])]
```

My `yhat_p` size is `[n_classes, n_samples]` instead of `[n_samples, n_classes]`. Can someone tell me why my output is transposed? Note: The `.predict()` method works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By binarizing your data, you have transformed the problem so you are now doing four separate classification tasks.  Each of those tasks has two classes, 0 and 1, where 1 represents "has this label" and 0 represents "doesn't have this label").

The formatting in the docs is a little odd, but it says:

> array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes], or a list of n_outputs such arrays if n_outputs > 1

Since you have four outputs, you get a list of four arrays.  Each of those arrays is of shape (2, 2), because you have two samples (i.e., two rows in your X_test) and two classes (0 and 1) for each output.  The `n_classes` referred to in the docs is the number of classes *for a single output*, not the total number of classes across all output classifications you're doing.  (The reason it returns a list instead of a single array is that it's not required that the separate classifications have the same number of classes.  You could do a multi-output classification task where one output has two classes and another has 100 classes.)

For instance, the first element in your list is

```
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0.7,  0.3]]),
```

Each row is giving you the probability that the corresponding row of `X_test` belongs to each of the classes in the first classiciation task, which is essentially "Is this item blue or not?"  Thus the first row is telling you that there is a 50% chance that the first `X_test` row is not blue and a 50% chance it is blue; the second row is telling you that there is a 70% chance that the second `X_test` row is not blue and a a 30% chance it is blue.

Comment: "The n_classes referred to in the docs is the number of classes for a single output, not the total number of classes across all output classifications you're doing" - that'll do it. Thanks